# Нужна помощь с УРАВНЕНИЕМ на PYTHON!

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Картинка]

```
import math

a = float(0.7)
b = float(0.05)
x = float(0.5)

print("y = ", (math.sqrt((x * b) / a) + (math.cos(((x + b)**3)**2))))
```

Когда я решаю уравнение в Photomath, у = 1.16156, а у меня получается 1.1885991520333594

Comment: у тебя вроде (x+b)  возводится в третью степень и потом в квадрат, а не cos от его третьей степени. убери скобку одну после math.cos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в расстановке скобок - здесь вы вычисляете `cos` от `( (x + b) ** 3) ** 2` вместо возведения в квадрат значения косинуса:
:

```
math.cos(((x + b)**3)**2)))
```

должно быть так:

```
math.cos( (x + b) ** 3) ** 2
```

все исправленное выражение:

```
math.sqrt(x*b/a) + math.cos((x+b)**3) ** 2
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!